# Laravel 5 - Auth Middleware dont protect route but throw error message

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with my auth middleware. I want to protect my routes with it, but in some controllers it dosent work really.
If I check the routes as logout user, I got different error messasges instead of blocking the access and redirect to the login page.
I use the middleware always over the __construct() in the controllers.

An example.

Controller

```
public function show(Dialog $dialog)
{
    return $this->template($dialog, self::DISPLAY_MODE_DIALOG);
}

protected function template(Dialog $dialog, $displayMode, $messageLimit = 10)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Check if the profile is currently controlled by the current user
    $isControlled = $dialog->moderator()->appProfile()->isControlledBy($user->id);
    $messageList  = $dialog->latestMessages($messageLimit);

    return view('dialog.chat.template')
        ->with(compact('dialog', 'messageList', 'isControlled', 'displayMode'));
}
```

Model

```
public function isAccessibleBy(User $user)
{
    $profile = $this->moderator()->appProfile();
    return  $profile->isOwner($user->id)
                    || $profile->isControlledBy($user->id);
}
```

Error

> Argument 1 passed to App\Model\Dialog\Dialog::isAccessibleBy() must be an         instance of App\Model\Account\User, null given, called in C:\projekte\php\newchat\app\Model\Dialog\Dialog.php on line 332 and defined

Now I realize why this happens, but i think the middleware should dont show this messages an protecte the route.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware

> "However, if the user is authenticated, the middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the application."

Comment: Could you extend your question with the constructor in your controller?

Comment: I always use the middleware like this .

`code` 
public function __construct() {
   $this->middleware('auth);
}
`code`

Comment: You are using model binding in your routes, so its get called before your controller, before your middleware.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: The quickest way if your check the user in `isAccessibleBy(User $user = null)`... Then `if($user) ...` set accessible, return false if the user is null

Answer (score 0):

I fix my Problem with the Solution from ryanmortier.
The Way from LPMadness dosent work for me.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6118